# Java GUI jdbc table search box

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am beginner and currently I am programming Java GUI application which connects to MySQL database and retrieves data from table `employees`. I need to program, when someone write text into `jTextFieldSearch` and click on `jButtonSearch`, it has to search corresponding value in `jTable1` and select that row. Up to now, I wrote this part of code and I don't know how to continue. Thank you very much!

```
private void jButtonSearchActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){                                              
        String expression = jTextFieldSearch.getText();
    }
```

[Picture (application)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjZSF.png)

Comment: So, you want to filter the `JTable`? Maybe you should start with [How to use JTable: Sorting and Filtering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting)

Comment: Possible duplicate [How can I filter rows in a JTable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107911/how-can-i-filter-rows-in-a-jtable)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thank you, but I have already read this article and it didn't help me because it doesn't work. I have class SimpleTableModel which extends class AbstractTableModel so I cannot use this RowSorter. And it is NOT duplicate as I ask for help for this particular application and not generally.

Comment: What a load of misunderstanding.  Dear lord, this is like my bread and butter - something I do ALL the time.  And, I since I could close your question with a single close vote, believe me, I'm seeking community input into my suggestion ;).  Before you "tell me" it "doesn't work", please back it up with a [mcve], because I have more then enough examples and experience making it work

Comment: [Example with real time filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26031383/how-to-filter-jtable-with-respect-to-a-specific-column/26031896#26031896) - Remember, you need to write a `RowSorter` which supports your `TableModel`

Comment: [Another real time, inline, filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29500713/overlay-swing-text-label-as-text-is-entered/29506154#29506154)